# Adding another subquery

Tags: mysql

I have this query as my main query, I use all the records from the members table, and selected  columns from comments and chat_box.

```
SELECT members.*, 
       a.commenter_id, 
       b.user_id, 
       a.comcount, 
       b.chatcount 
FROM   members 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT commenter_id, 
                         Count(*) comCount 
                  FROM   comments 
                  GROUP  BY commenter_id) a 
              ON members.id = a.commenter_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, 
                         Count(*) chatCount 
                  FROM   chat_box 
                  GROUP  BY user_id) b 
              ON members.id = b.user_id 
WHERE  members.id = '290'
```

I would like to add this query to the above

```
SELECT Count(friend_id) AS totFriend, 
       friend_id        AS fi, 
       logged_user_id   AS user, 
       friend_accepted  AS fa 
FROM   member_friends 
WHERE  logged_user_id = '1' 
       AND friend_id = '290'
```

Is it possible to add this to the mix without causing any errors? I have tried it myself but I maybe just putting my self in deeper problems. If it is possible could someone assist me in doing so, thank you :).

Comment: how does the `member_friends` table relate to the others?

Comment: member_friends only would related to the members table, by way of friend_id, if the logic is bad then I will understand if it cant be done hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a way to join the last query to your `members` table, then you should be able to use:

```
SELECT members.*, 
  a.commenter_id, 
  b.user_id, 
  a.comcount, 
  b.chatcount,
  c.totFriend
FROM   members 
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT commenter_id, 
    Count(*) comCount 
  FROM   comments 
  GROUP  BY commenter_id
) a 
  ON members.id = a.commenter_id 
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT user_id, 
    Count(*) chatCount 
  FROM   chat_box 
  GROUP  BY user_id
) b 
 ON members.id = b.user_id 
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT Count(friend_id) AS totFriend, 
       friend_id        AS fi, 
       logged_user_id   AS user, 
       friend_accepted  AS fa 
  FROM   member_friends 
  WHERE  logged_user_id = '1' 
   AND friend_id = '290'
) c
  on members.id = c.friend_id
WHERE  members.id = '290'
```